# Parameter confidence intervals which include errors in data

Tags: confidence-interval, fitting, uncertainty

My question seems to be very basic one but my search has not given any similar question. I have small dataset of 8 $(x,y)$ values with uncertainties for $y$ (dependent variable) and the theory predicts quadratic dependence $y=a x^2 + b x + c$. I wish to fit this dataset to the quadratic equation and to calculate confidence intervals for the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ based both on the residuals (they are very small, i.e. the quadratic model describes the experimental data with very small residuals) and on declared uncertainty for every measurement (the uncertainties are much bigger than the residuals). What is the most correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the OP's response to my questions, I'd suggest [boostrapping](http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/21122_Chapter_21.pdf), which will take into account the possibility that your small sample size results in overfitting the model.
I would look into the body of theory called Error in Variables Regression. See [link](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec524/Merr_new.pdf) and [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models)

Comment: Other, related search terms include Deming regression, Model II regression, total least squares.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Thank you for the links, they give some information but no formulas. According to the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) you provided, "errors-in-variables models are regression models that account for measurement errors in the **independent variables**" (emphasis mine). In my case I assume that the independent variable `x` has no error and the error of dependent variable `y` is known. Your [first link](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec524/Merr_new.pdf) contains formula only for linear model with error in the independent variable.

Comment: @Alexey: I guess I am having trouble understanding what you mean by uncertainty in y, apart from the residuals. If your model has small residuals, then in general that is good and indicates that the model accounts for most of the uncertainty in Y. Hoever, since you have a small model, you are using up 1/2 of your degrees of freedom by fitting a quadratic model, so there is a potential for bias vs. fit. Is that what you are tryign to account for?

Comment: (cont'd) It might help if you write out the probability model for your problem, then we can all offer more constructive help. Based on your description, it sounds like you are trying to model the following: $\mu_{y|x} + \epsilon = ax^2 + bx + c$ This represents a classic polynomial regression problem. Is that the case, or would Y be uncertain even with no measurement error (i.e., Y is inherently random, ala Quantum Mechanics or Economics)? Answering this question would help me offer more relevant links.

Comment: I am not a statistician and not familiar with the notation. Yes, it is a polynomial regression problem. The uncertainty of measurement is known for each $y_i$ and I assume that $x_i$ has no error. The model $y=a x^2 + b x + c$ describes data with much smaller residuals that the reported measurement uncertainties. This indicates that random noise is small but do not guarantee that there is no systematic error in measurements.

Comment: Based on the reported uncertainties I wish to estimate confidence intervals for parameters and if possible to separate contributions of random noise and of possible systematic error. I am especially interested in the value of parameter $c$.

Comment: Answering your last question, Y is not inherently random, it is well-defined physical quantity which is measured directly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Thanks for the link, but I think that my problem is very common and basic, and I expected something simpler: a few formulas how to compute confidence intervals. I feel that bootstrapping is a kind of overkill in my case. I do not think that small sample size results in overfitting the model since residuals are really small. Bootstrapping surely can give the most reasonable estimates for confidence intervals but in my case I think something much simpler should give almost the same result.

Comment: common, yes, simple...not always. Small residuals should make you more suspisious of overfitting, not less. If the residuals are normal, then you can use the T-distribution to form confidence intervals from the standard errors of the coefficients (which you will get from the polynomial regression output): $\hat \beta_i \pm t_{\alpha/2,n-k-1}\hat s_{\hat \beta_i}$ where $\hat \beta_i$ is the point estimate for coefficient i and $\hat s_{\hat \beta_i}$ is its standard error. The following link may be helpful:http://www.stat.lsu.edu/faculty/geaghan/exst7034/fall2005/pdf/17-polynomials.pdf

Comment: But how should I use the reported uncertainties of measurements?

Comment: You don't. Regression is precisely for when you have uncertain measurement on Y. You will not end up using your assumed uncertainty in Y, it should be reflected in the residuals. If you are concerned that the small residuals is the result of spurious fitting to a small dataset, then you will need to do boostrapping to estimate the contribution from small-sample bias vs. residual error. The CIs from a regression package will not differentiate for you, and it is not a simple calcuation.

Comment: But for what is weighted fitting in this case? I thought that weights are reciprocal standard deviations (i.e. uncertaities).

Comment: Yes, you can use weighted least squares: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm which allows you to enter your specific errors for each measurement. Then you can use the standard errors from the package to form your CIs.

Comment: My question is: what is the most correct way to estimate the confidence intervals? Weighted least squares and ordinary least squares are possible, but which way is the most correct?

Comment: Ok, that is a very specific question. If you assume you know, or are asserting, a particular measurement uncertainty, use weighted least squares, then you let your more precise data drive the estimate.

Comment: Actually, I cannot completely trust the uncertainties reported in the publication because the method of calculation of the uncertainties is not stated precisely. Your [last link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm) is very helpful here because it says that we should not consider the reported uncertainties if we unsure that they are correct. I think this link finally answers my question although no exact formulae for CI are given (I trust my software which automatically calculates the ANOVA table but I would wish to understand the background).

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_i$ be true value of $y_i$.  If $z_i \sim N(y_i, \Delta y_i)$, and the theory predicts $z_i=a x_i^2$ then you should minimize $$\sum_i \left( {a x_i^2 + b x_i + c - y_i \over \Delta y_i} \right)^2$$

This is a weighted linear regression problem.

Comment: The theory predicts $z_i=a x_i^2 + b x_i + c$. And I need to compute confidence intervals, especially for the free term $c$.

Comment: The answer is edited.